# How to remove html tags and contents in between them in c#?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to remove the  tag and contents between them from my source..

Following is my source:

```
<tr>
  <td class="ds_label" width="40%" style="font-size: 70%;"></td>
  <td id="table_cell_1585" class="ds_label">
    <a class="tt" href="#" onClick="return false;">
      <table class="tooltip" style="width:300px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border=0>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td class="ds_data" width="60%" style="font-size: 70%">800 x 480 pixels</td>
</tr>
```

And i want to remove whole `<a>` tag with content.

I used this:
response contains my source code.

```
response = Regex.Replace(response, "<a>(.|\n)*?</a>", string.Empty);
```

but it's not working.

Please advise.

Comment: What source are you referring to?

Comment: Obligatory mention of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not - Regex isn't a good tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: I am passing one link to HttpWebRequest and getting HttpWebResponse.And from that response I want to remove <a> tag with contents in between

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not a good tool for parsing HTML.  Take a look at [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead to save yourself some work.

Comment: can you pls tell me how to do it?

Comment: No, we cannot.  Please try out the assembly and ask relevant questions after you have reached a stopping point.  You'll learn better this way.

Answer (score 2):

- Firstly, try to avoid using regex to work with HTML, it's the wrong tool because there are too many edge cases to be reliable or secure. Use a framework designed to work with a structured document like the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).
- When you are using literal strings to define a regular expression in c# it's a good idea to use a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (prefixed with `@`) so escape caracters in the pattern arn't interpreted as part of the literal string. In the case of this question `@"<a>(.|\n)*?</a>"` will stop the `\n` from being treated as an escape character in c#.
- New lines can consist of both `\r` and-or `\n`
- HTML `A` tags contain attributes like href so `<a>` is unlikely to match anything because of the closing `>`
- Use `RegexOptions.Singleline` in the options argument to ensure `.` matches any character including newlines.

---

This unit test succeeds.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"<a.*?</a>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    string input = "foo <a href=\"//example.com\">\r\nbaz</a> bar";
    string expected = "foo  bar";
    string actual = pattern.Replace(input, string.Empty);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

However, be aware that this is not a secure way of handling user input or any kind of data that is not pre-defined because regular expressions like this can easily be evaded.

Answer (score 1):

use this

variable =  Server.HtmlDecode(variable).Trim();

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

---

```
    [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var source =
                @"
<tr>
  <td class='ds_label' width='40%' style='font-size: 70%;\'></td>
  <td id='table_cell_1585' class='ds_label'>
    <a class='tt' href='#' onClick='return false;'>
      <table class='tooltip' style='width:300px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border=0>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td class='ds_data' width='60%' style='font-size: 70%'>800 x 480 pixels</td>
</tr>";
            source = Regex.Replace(source, "<a [^>]*>", string.Empty);
            source = Regex.Replace(source, "</a>", string.Empty);
            Console.Write(source);
        }
```

Comment: i have tried this it is not working.Can u pls suggest me any other way?

Comment: could you paste the result here, after using my regex? edit this answer or edit your question. Or use pastebin.com or gist.github to collaborate.

Comment: I used : response = Regex.Replace(response, "<a[^>]*?>.*?</a>", String.Empty);

Comment: Look at the edited answer, and mark right if it solved your question. And your regex did not work - the anchor tag, in your question source still remained.

Comment: Its working..

I passed the response  from that <a[^>]*?>.*?</a> tag removed by String.Empty.Response is the variable which contain all the html source code.